# Select a dom element with jQuery does not work with this id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a strange behaviour, maybe I'm missing something.

I have this DOM element (Sharepoint Ribbon Element, but doesn't matter) which I want to select with jQuery by ID:

```
<span class="ms-cui-row" 
id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font-Medium-0-0">...</span>
```

If I select it with the class name `$('.ms-cui-row')` I can select it but with the id I can't `$('#Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font-Medium-0-0')`. I can't even select it with `$('[id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font-Medium-0-0"]')`.

So whats the point here? Maybe its not a good idea to use dots in an id name - but that was Microsoft not me and I can't change it. But it seems to be ok for them?

I prepared a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxEQe/1/)** to play around with.

Comment: Check this: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F

Comment: You must escape: `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^\`{|}~`

Comment: Microsoft is putting dots in every market that Apple is in even id attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have `.` in a jQuery selector (except at the beginning of a class selector), since jQuery will assume it is referring to a class on the element. Escape it with `\\`.

Also, the id selector in jQuery is `$("#id")`.

Your new selector:

```
$('#Ribbon\\.EditingTools\\.CPEditTab\\.Font-Medium-0-0')
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I appreciate it. And I tried to use `\` but just one, not two. But as you have seen that doesn't work either...

Comment: The problem is the `document.write`, my bad: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RDCMU/

Comment: @Marc: `'#Ribbon\\.EditingTools\\.CPEditTab\\.Font-Medium-0-0'` works fine.

Comment: @nbrooks: Thanks, thats it! I had an error in my check script so you were right and your answer is correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: I got tripped up by the `document.write` erasing everything (and thus removing the `<span>` we were looking for) on my first checks as well.

Comment: yeah that's the problem I was having too. I didn't realize `document.write` would overwrite the whole html.

Answer (score 2):

```
alert($('#Ribbon\\.EditingTools\\.CPEditTab\\.Font-Medium-0-0').length)
```

Works for me.

Comment: Hm, not for me... I'm on Chrome, which browser do you use?

Comment: Ahh it works for me as well, sorry, I think I had a mistake in my fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following ways to select an id with special characters:

`$('[id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Font-Medium-0-0"]');` [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/x5j86/1/)

`$('#Ribbon\\.EditingTools\\.CPEditTab\\.Font-Medium-0-0');` [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/x5j86/2/)

References:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F
- http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/